# libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed by skypeforlinux-8.9.0.1-1.x86_64

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, skype

My environment:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -q glibc
glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686
$
```

I'm trying to follow [Download Skype | Free calls | Chat app](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/):

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
Retrieving https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed by skypeforlinux-8.9.0.1-1.x86_64
$
```

am I doing something wrong? or is it on Microsoft's side?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you are running Centos 7. When issuing the command `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` in Centos 7, it shows the following output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

This means that right now Centos doesn't support the version of glibc (, i.e., GLIBCXX_3.4.20) that is required by the latest version of Skype (v8.9).

If wish to install Skype in Centos at the moment, you can have a look at the nux repo which hosts a precompiled version of skype (probably an older version). Or you could always build the latest glibc from source and then try to install Skype.

Comment: I'm on RHEL 7.4 and I'm seeing this problem too

Comment: As said, nothing can be done for the time being if you are using stock glibc. Update has to come from upstream maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the content of package, for example rpm:

```
$ rpm2cpio skypeforlinux-64.rpm | cpio -id
```

and then run it (from location that you have extracted it):

```
$ usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
```

---

Info about glibc 3.4.20:

It looks that the only file that wants it is cld.node (usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/cld/build/Release/cld.node)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made an attempt at fixing this for CentOS/RHEL 7 in unstable build 8.11.76.3 available [here](https://repo.skype.com/rpm/unstable/). More info is available in [this CentOS thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=64844).

Answer (score 0):

... not the best way to go, however one can use `--nodeps`, like this:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm --nodeps
Retrieving https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:skypeforlinux-8.9.0.1-1          ################################# [100%]
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start atd.service
$ echo $?
0
$
```

another way to go would be to downgrade to older version of skype:

next step is only applicable if you used `--nodeps` option, otherwise skip to next step:

```
$ sudo yum remove skypeforlinux
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, nvidia
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package skypeforlinux.x86_64 0:8.9.0.1-1 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch                 Version                  Repository               Size
=========================================================================================================
Removing:
 skypeforlinux               x86_64               8.9.0.1-1                installed               206 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================
Remove  1 Package

Installed size: 206 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Erasing    : skypeforlinux-8.9.0.1-1.x86_64                                                        1/1 
  Verifying  : skypeforlinux-8.9.0.1-1.x86_64                                                        1/1 

Removed:
  skypeforlinux.x86_64 0:8.9.0.1-1                                                                       

Complete!
$
```

go ahead and install older version of `skypeforlinux`:

```
$ sudo yum install skypeforlinux-5.5.0.1-1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, nvidia
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * elrepo: reflector.westga.edu
 * epel: mirror.nodesdirect.com
 * extras: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.metrocast.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package skypeforlinux.x86_64 0:5.5.0.1-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch                Version                  Repository                 Size
=========================================================================================================
Installing:
 skypeforlinux              x86_64              5.5.0.1-1                skype-stable               69 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 69 M
Installed size: 69 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
skypeforlinux_5.5.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm                                                |  69 MB  00:00:35     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : skypeforlinux-5.5.0.1-1.x86_64                                                        1/1 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start atd.service
  Verifying  : skypeforlinux-5.5.0.1-1.x86_64                                                        1/1 

Installed:
  skypeforlinux.x86_64 0:5.5.0.1-1                                                                       

Complete!
$
```

Comment: `--nodeps` can be dangerous...Missing libs in this case may cause Skype malfunction. You can use `yum provides libstdc*` to see what package provides the missing lib, then install the package before installing Skype with `rpm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `libstc++.so.6.0.20`, which contains `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` and it's compiled for `glibc-2.17`. Then put it to `/usr/lib64` and relink existing `libstdc++.so.6` to it.

For example, the appropriate library can be found in this package - https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/r/ra/ramonelinux/Rel_0.99/releases/x86_64/packages/gcc-libstdc++-4.9.1-1.ram0.99.x86_64.html

P.S. The dependencies will be still failing. But at least Skype will run after installation.

Comment: This link is Dead.

Answer (score -1):

Download https://repo.skype.com/rpm/stable/skypeforlinux_5.5.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
and install it by
yum localinstall skypeforlinux_5.5.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
Works for me on CentOS 7.

Comment: This reply is too succinct to be of real use: it does not address the problem of the failed dependency. The fact that it works for your pc, where most likely the set of installed programs is altogether different, does not mean it will work on a subtly different installation. A really  useful answer would entail explaining how to fully diagnose the case of the un-installable dependency. Please try to expand on this point, if you think you can be of assistance.